# Resize method intArray

Tags: c++, resize

I'm writting an `IntArray` class for college but don't know how to write my `resize` method efficiently. What I have doesn't support resizing to smaller lists and I don't know how to fix that..

Here is my code:

```
 void IntArray::resize(unsigned int size){
     for (int i = size;i<length;i++){
         data[i] = 0;
     }
     length = size;
 }
```

header file

```
#ifndef INTARRAY_H_
#define INTARRAY_H_

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class IntArray{
private:
     int length;
     int * data;
public:
    IntArray(int size = 0);
    IntArray(const IntArray& other);
    IntArray& operator=(const IntArray& original);

    int getSize() const { return length; };
    int& operator[](unsigned int i);
    void resize(unsigned int size);
    void insertBefore(int value, int index);

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const IntArray& list);
    ~IntArray(){ delete[] data; };
};
```

Comment: just use a std::vector

Comment: @user3528438 Since it's for college I'm guessing the purpose of the assignment is to learn how to do this (i.e., not use an existing container type).

Comment: it's a task for college. I need to write a arraylist class.

Comment: i will add my header file

Comment: I wouldn't expect a function called `resize()` sets all of my existing data to `0`.

Comment: the resize will reduce my list so the values that are out of 'bounds' will get 0 value, that's not a good way to do it?

Comment: The most efficient/cleanest way to do it, without using STL, is to use `realloc`, which is again probably banned by your instructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you need to resize an you are actually going to create a new array, copy the old into the new and then delete the old array.

```
 void IntArray::resize(unsigned int size){
     if (size <= length)  // if we are making it smaller reset the size and do nothnig
     {
        my_size = size
        return;
     }
     int * temparr = new int[size];
     // copy data
     for (unsigned int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
        temparr[i] = data[i];
     delete [] data; // get rid of the old array
     data = temparr; // set data to the new array
     length = size; // set the new size
 }
```

You should also have a capacity member that tracks the actual size of the array like a `std::vector`.  That way you can have an array that is bigger than what you need to as it grows there would need to be less re -llocations.

Comment: No, it'll be freed when you free `data`

Comment: No.  if you `delete` temparr then you would get rid of the new array.  Since we are doing `data = temparr` then the memory will be taken care of in you class destructor.